# AssertionError: path must be a string is thrown when requiring own module

Tags: node.js, require

I wanted to create a very minified version of [hapi-ninja](https://github.com/poeticninja/hapi-ninja) and came across following problem:

```
var settings = require('./app/server/config/settings');
var routes = require('./app/server/config/rout');
```

The first line works as it should an returns my modules. But the second line throws following Exception

```
AssertionError: path must be a string
at Module.require (module.js:362:3)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hknlof/development/mygit/todos/app/server/config/rout.js:8:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hknlof/development/mygit/todos/tryout.js:1:75)
```

I am running on Node v0.10.25 and [hapi-ninja](https://github.com/poeticninja/hapi-ninja) is working fine. When I don't require the rout module it does work. My rout and settings modules look very much the same as in hapi-ninja. I isolated the two require statements in one file. Tried both on their own, still the same result. Can't get my head around this. Tried debugging but the value of the node internal `path` does never change to the above string. Encoding ist always utf-8.

Comment: so, what's inside `rout.js` on line 8?

Comment: rout.js line 8 is where your error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [vkuchartkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391953/vkurchatkin) and [Tracker1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43906/tracker1). 
So my mistake was that I forgot to require a certain directory in my rout.js

```
var getController = require(module, '../controller');
```

was my code. Should have been:

```
var requireDir = require('require-directory');
var get Controller = requireDir(module, '../controller');
```

Now I feel a bit stupid